# Laravel 4.2 SQL Server - PDOException - could not find driver

Tags: sql-server, exception, laravel-4

I got the error on the title in my project (which is working well in production on remote server). My local server is Apache, WAMP package.

By default, SQL Server is the database conection so I can't even login. I'm going to share many screenshots because I try many solutions what I found while searching on Google but no one fix my issue.

First of all, the exception message which is almost the same for everyone.
[[image: PDOExcpetion error message[1]]

So now, my System variables with PHP and Postgrade path.
[image: Postgrade path on System's variables]

[image: PHP Path on System's variables]

Here is the PHP Extension list enabled/disabled
[image]

And the "extension_dir" on PHP.ini
[image]

Finally, laravel files setting up the connection...

start.php -> set my "local" environment
[image]

and my local/database.php settings

[image]

So I got eveything properly setted (I think) and even like this I can't connect.
Any some other help, please?

Comment: I forgot to tell, WAMP is using port 8080, I don't know if is necessary for sql server or something else... Application is runing til login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was the arquitecture used on WAMP, should be 32bits, not 64 as I got.